# How to initialise struct with constant members with certain address?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, constants

I am trying to initialise class object (which has constant members) with certain values and certain address. I understand that this is because members are constant but I need them to be constant. I tried to find solution but with no success.

So the question is: is there some "easy" way to do it?

```
class ints{
    public:
        const int a;
        const int b;
        ints(int a, int b);
    };

ints::ints(int a, int b) :
    a{a},
    b{b}
{}

int main() {
    auto ptr = (ints*)malloc(sizeof(ints));
    ints values{1, 2};
 // all wrong
//    *ptr = ints copy{values}; 
//    &values = ptr;
//    *ptr = values;
    std::cout << ptr->a; //ptr->a should be equal to 1
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for placement new? Note that constant members are often a poor approach

Comment: Don't use malloc in c++

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but what's wrong with `auto ptr = new ints{ 1,2 };`?

Comment: "_and certain address_": An explanation of _why_ you need that and how you determine this address would make it easier to give you an answer that fits your problem appropriately.

Comment: No you don't *need* `const` members. You can choose not to touch them.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object at a specific address using placement-new:

```
extern void* some_address;

int main()
{
    ints* ptr = new(some_address) ints{1, 2};
    std::cout << ptr->a;
}
```